# Add properties to array

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
    $data = @(
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:04:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:04:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:03:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:03:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:03:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:05:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:03:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='2';Id2=11112314;ID3='00:03:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:02:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:04:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='1';Id2=51213412;ID3='00:05:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='4';Id2=42112521;ID3='00:01:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='3';Id2=12512521;ID3='00:05:00'}
   [pscustomobject]@{Id1='5';Id2=53252352;ID3='00:01:00'})
```

I would like to convert property ID3, that is time to display only minutes so I can ultimately make a sum of them. I found a code that can convert it to minutes:

```
$minutes = foreach ($mins in $data.ID3) {
$TimeSpan = [System.TimeSpan]::Parse($mins)
[System.Math]::Round($TimeSpan.TotalMinutes,0)}
```

But now I get the results in $minutes variable. What is the fastest way to replace ID3 values with converted value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calculated property expression with `Select-Object` to select a new "column" based on the value of an existing property:

```
$data |Select-Object ID1,ID2,ID3,@{Name='Minutes';Expression={[math]::Round([timespan]::Parse($_.ID3).TotalMinutes, 0)}}
```

This will create a new object for every input object, each with the 3 properties from the input object and a new property `Minutes` with the parsed value

If you want to "overwrite" the existing `ID3` property, simply omit it from the list of property names and supply it as the name for the calculated property instead:

```
$data |Select-Object ID1,ID2,@{Name='ID3';Expression={[math]::Round([timespan]::Parse($_.ID3).TotalMinutes, 0)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the object's values, you can enumerate them and reassign them like this:

```sh
foreach($i in $data) {
    $i.ID3 = ([timespan] $i.ID3).Minutes
}
```

However, since you mention you want the sum of them, you might be just looking for this:

```sh
[timespan]::FromMilliseconds(
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum(
        [int[]] ([timespan[]] $data.ID3).TotalMilliseconds
    )
).TotalMinutes
```